# Different between Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook and Facebook SDK for Javascript Oauth2

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, facebook-graph-api, google-signin, owin-middleware

In Asp.Net MVC we can Use to authenticate Login with  Social Media (like Facebook,Google,Linkedin)
to using  OWIN middleware
Library **what are the benefits to use this library** 
instead of the javaScript SDK provided by social media???
Or **Both Are Same?**

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript SDK only allows the implementation of the client-side login flow; whereas such frameworks often use the server-side login flow.

Of course you can combine both - get a user access token on the client side by using the JS SDK, and then send that token to the server-side part of your application, to then use it to perform API calls from there. But then you’d get more into the territory of implementing basic functionality yourself, working around the framework … so that probably doesn’t make much sense in most cases.